# Contains string without a character

Tags: regex

I feel like this should be pretty straight forward but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Say, for example, we have the following string:
"Photos Photo"

I want to write a regex that returns the "Photo" part of the string but does not return the "Photos" part because it has an "s" in it. How would I write this regex?

Comment: `Photo(?!s)` or `Photo\b`

Comment: For a complete answer, you might need to provide a more complete example.

Comment: 1) Can you provide more examples of inputs and expected outputs, and 2) what have your tried?

Comment: Do you want to eliminate words that end in s or all words with an s?

Comment: You might want to do some searching into *negative lookahead*

Comment: @Ulugbek got it. For reference, the specific use case was the return from a Capybara test that in some instances would have both "Photos" and "Photo". I wanted to make sure the "Photo" singular was present and that Capybara wasn't just passing because "Photos" was in the return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to write such a `regexp`, you have to refine your conditions in order to get the best one.

Assuming you need to match `Photo` only when it is a complete word and not a part of a longer word, the expression is:

```
/\bPhoto\b/
```

The `\b` pieces are special `regexp` constructs that match word boundaries i.e. the transition between a word character (letters, digits, underscore) and a non-word character (anything else).

The forward slashes (`/`) are not part of the `regexp`, they are delimiter. Some tools and languages require them, the editors and IDEs usually don't need them, some tools allow the user pick the delimiter (from a not very large list).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab a word that does not have an s in it use this...

```
([A-Ra-r]|[T-Zt-z])+\s
```